# Center Cropping Image

Tags: html, css, image

I need to center crop a landscape image inside a vertical box (eg 600 X 400)I have the following html code with the css code for center cropping. But the output image is not center cropped and it is also stretched.

```
<div id="posts">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="#"> 
           <img src="Vasco45_barbosa.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

 #posts .image {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 600px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#posts .image img{
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block; 
    min-width: 100%;  
    min-height: 100%;  
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; 
}
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmz6s.jpg)

[Image after applying the above css code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weZl1.png)

Comment: I'm not seeing the second stretched image you've linked to. Instead I see an unstretched section of the left side of the original image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change img css to this

```
#posts .image img{
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: 50% 50%; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

How it works: https://jsfiddle.net/6ns549hy/

Comment: **Works as expected**

Comment: This solution support all the browser?? @pawel Michalski

Comment: Most - IE / Edge is not supported (yet, it is considered to be) but there are some fixes and workarounds like https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit